# external file content <textarea>

Tags: html, file, textarea, external

Is it possible in HTML/Javascript (NO PHP) to put for example the content of the file 
`file.txt` in a `<textarea>` and how ?

I actually want to view the source code of the file in a `<textarea>`

THX

Evert

****EDIT****
`file.txt` was an example, actually the html is in a .sqlite file (with also a lot of other text) but my page just shows a specific html code in it (long story) but i wan to get that whole content of the .sqlite file in a text area

Comment: Why would you do that? Which problem do you expect it to solve?

Comment: Well, i actually want to view the source code of the file in a '<textarea>'

Comment: @eds1999, which “source code”? The name extension “.txt” suggests plain text.

Comment: It was an example, actually the html is in a .sqlite file (with also a lot of other text) but my page just shows a specific html code in it (long story) but i wan to get that whole content of the .sqlite file in a text area

Comment: You just want a static content of the file to be displayed? Why not just copy+paste it into page source code?

Comment: because i haven't create that file, i can just edit a little part of it (that HTML), and the file is constantly changing… the text area has to adjust every time you refresh...

Comment: So why `textarea`? Does it need to be treated as default for user input?

Comment: yep, or `<input type="text" value="HERE THE CODE">` Is also possible :)